# How do I create a dummy for the last year observation per firm in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to create a dummy variable equal to 1 for the last year per firm, and zero otherwise, that looks like this:

```
data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "dummy" : [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I was wondering what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'` parameter and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['dummy1'] = np.where(df['firm'].duplicated(keep='last'), 0, 1)
```

Or invert mask with convert `True,False` to `1,0` by [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['dummy1'] = (~df['firm'].duplicated(keep='last')).view('i1')
#alternative
#df['dummy1'] = (~df['firm'].duplicated(keep='last')).astype('int')
print (df)
    firm  year  dummy  dummy1
0      1  2000      0       0
1      1  2001      0       0
2      1  2002      0       0
3      1  2003      1       1
4      2  1990      0       0
5      2  1991      0       0
6      2  1992      0       0
7      2  1993      0       0
8      2  1994      1       1
9      3  2010      0       0
10     3  2011      0       0
11     3  2012      1       1
12     4  2005      0       0
13     4  2006      0       0
14     4  2007      0       0
15     4  2008      0       0
16     4  2009      0       0
17     4  2010      1       1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I would have a follow up question. I would like to do the same thing as above but adding one condition, that var == 1. So, if I had a dataframe like this: `data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "var" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df` and I wanted to include the condition that dummy variable only applies to var == 1 so I get a dummy like this

Comment: `data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "var" : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], "dummy" : [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df`

Comment: @mxhet - then use `df['dummy1'] = np.where(~df['firm'].duplicated(keep='last') & df['var'].eq(1), 1,0)`